# Quarkus - Embedded Distributed Cache

Tags: quarkus, distributed-caching

Is there any embedded distributed cache available in quarkus? I see Infinispan embedded extension has been removed some time back.

[Why is Infinispan Embedded extension removed?](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/13123)

My requirement is to have a quarkus java application that has an embedded cache (something like infinispan or hazelcast, etc.) that distributes data across multiple pods in a kubernetes cluster. Any one could suggest a way to achieve this, without running a separate cache cluster?

Comment: There isn't anything that I know of

Comment: Thanks @geoand, will wait for any other suggestions from others

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast has some interesting guides, take a look in the following to see hazelcast microprofile embedded:

https://guides.hazelcast.org/hazelcast-embedded-microprofile/

Or [here](https://guides.hazelcast.org/home/) to see all the hazelcast available guides.